# summary of several google sheets in one another sheet

Tags: google-sheets-query

Hi have several sheet in a single google sheet for each of the months with some data. I want t have a summary sheet (annual) with some info I am after.

For example, in a sheet called Jan I have the following
Cell A         B     C
     Date      Cat   Amount
     05/01/16  Shop  100
     10/01/16  Other 50

In another sheet (called Feb) in the same file, I have
Cell A         B     C
     Date      Cat   Amount
     07/02/16  Shop  200
     11/02/16  Other 500

Now, I want to have another sheet, preferably in the same file, the following.(which is accumulation of all data in the two sheets above for just one category)
05/01/2017 Shop 100
 07/02/16  Shop  200

my question is what is the formulae I good use to get above (I do not want to copy paste)

Comment: anyone please? I tried query=, while I can do this for one sheet, one sure how I can select multiple sheets ? i tired =query({Jan!A:F;Feb!A:F},'select A'); etc but it did not worl..any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
       =query({Jan!A:F;Feb!A:F},"select  *")
```

Try changing `A`  to `*`. You could also try to use Col1 Col2 instead of A or B. I think it would work.

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).

Comment: @Massimiliano Honestly, i don't think there's nothing much to explain. Almost all of the code is copied from the OP's  comment. I just changed the `A` to `*` .  If the OP has questions, I'm available to answer or debug, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below in sheet 3 in A1

```
={IMPORTRANGE("Sheet1!A1:D");IMPORTRANGE("Sheet2!A2:D")}
```

It will combine sheet1 data and sheet2 data in sheet3